# Can't see all rows after sql update

Tags: sql

I am trying to Set the value of AmountOwed in my TransactionDetail table based on a formula using fields from TransactionDetail and SalesDetail tables.  The inner Select query works and returns the expected value(s). The fields in use are of the following types:

```
TotalTender - money
PriceEntered - money
TaxRate - float
```

----- SQL Query -----

```
Update [POSDatabase].[dbo].[TransactionDetail]

    Set AmountOwed =  
    (Select (TotalTender - (Select sum(PriceEntered+(PriceEntered*TaxRate*.01)) 
                            from POSDB.dbo.SalesDetail as Sales 
                            where Sales.TransactionID = Trans.ID))

    From POSDB.dbo.TransactionDetail as Trans

    Where TransactionDetail.ID = Trans.ID)

    Where ID = 4207
```

----- End SQL Query -----

When I run this query it says it affected 1 row, but when I try to view the table (Select * from Table), the query just spins.  Oddly enough, if i scroll down, it has displayed all the records up to 5-6 less than the ID identified in this query.

I thought maybe I was having a data type mismatch, but same thing happens after a CONVERT or CAST has been done to change the result to a money type.

Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Please format your query to be readable without scrolling.

Comment: What database system are you using? (I'm guessing SQL Server, but just checking)

Answer (score 1):

I am having a hard time following your query but I think something like this might work if I am understanding correctly.

```
;with s (TransactionID, total) as (
    select  TransactionID, sum(PriceEntered+(PriceEntered*TaxRate*.01))
    from   [POSDB].[dbo].[SalesDetail]
    group by TransactionID
)
update  td
set     amountOwed = td.TotalTendered-s.total 
from    [POSDatabase].[dbo].[TransactionDetail] td 
    join  s on td.id = s.TransactionID
where   td.id = 4207
```